# missing `]' error in unix shell script

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to run a small script which check for two variables to see if they are empty or not.
I am getting the correct output but if also shows me error for missing right parenthesis. I tried using double parenthesis as well as round bracket but didn't work.

```
var=""
non="hi"

 if ([ -z "$var"] && [ -z "$non"])
then
    echo "both empty"

else
    echo "has data"
fi
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
line 6: [: missing `]'
has data
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a space bettween "$non" and ], and you don't need ()'s:

```
if [ -z "$var" ] && [ -z "$non" ]
```

Answer (score 4):

As Andy Dalton said in his answer you need a space between **"$non"** and the closing square parentheses **]** like this:

```
[ -z "$non" ]
```

I just want to add a bit of motivation why this is needed. In bash the square parentheses are commands (you can try **man [** to see, it's the manual for the **test** command), so you need the space for bash to figure out which command you are invoking.